# How to use entityframework 6 with mono and sqlite for C# cross-platform development?

Tags: c#, sqlite, mono, cross-platform, entity-framework-6

Is there any possibility to use the [EntityFramework 6](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/) for Windows & Linux & MacOS C# projects with the support of SQLite as db backend?

**Edit:**
We will use [DBreeze](http://dbreeze.codeplex.com/) as a replacement. EntityFramework and NuGet in combination with SQLite is not working "out of the box" like DBreeze does at the moment. I will still be very happy about a solution with EntityFramework.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [SQLite Code-First](https://github.com/msallin/SQLiteCodeFirst) (or search for it on NuGet).